# perl - moving files using wildcard

Tags: perl

Is it possible to use perl's `move` function from `File::Copy` module to use a wildcard to move a number of common files with the same file extension? 
So far, I can only get `move` to work if I explicitly name the files.

For example, I wanted to do something like so:

```
my $old_loc = "/share/cust/abc/*.dat";
my $arc_dir = "/share/archive_dir/";
```

Right now, I can do one file like so:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

my $old_loc = "/share/cust/abc/Mail_2011-10-17.dat";
my $arc_dir = "/share/archive_dir/Mail_2011-10-17.dat";
my $new_loc = $arc_dir;

#archive
print "Moving files to archive...\n";
move ($old_loc, $new_loc) || die "cound not move $old_loc to $new_loc: $!\n";
```

What I want to do at the end of my perl program, move all these files named `*.dat` to an archive directory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use Perl's [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) operator to get the list of files you need to open:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

my @old_files = glob "/share/cust/abc/*.dat";
my $arc_dir = "/share/archive_dir/";

foreach my $old_file (@old_files)
{
    my ($short_file_name) = $old_file =~ m~/(.*?\.dat)$~;
    my $new_file = $arc_dir . $short_file_name;

    move($old_file, $new_file) or die "Could not move $old_file to $new_file: $!\n";
}
```

This has the benefit of not relying on a system call, which is unportable, system-dependent, and possibly dangerous.

---

**EDIT**: A better way to do this is just to supply the new directory instead of the full new filename. (Sorry for not thinking of this earlier!)

```
    move($old_file, $arc_dir) or die "Could not move $old_file to $new_file: $!\n";
    # Probably a good idea to make sure $arc_dir ends with a '/' character, just in case
```

Comment: thanks. i am trying to get this to work, although, I'm confused on the line `my $new_file = $arc_dir . $short_file_name;`. The message is `/share/archive_dir/share/cust/abc/myfile.dat: No such file or directory`. I want the files going to `arc_dir`, but its combined the directories intead

Comment: That regex will match the entire path, because the `.*` is greedy. It is unnecessary to supply a file name however, unless you are renaming the file.

Answer (score 5):

From the File::Copy [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aCopy):

> If the destination already exists and is a directory, and the source
>   is not a directory, then the source file will be renamed into the
>   directory specified by the destination.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

my $old_loc = "/share/cust/abc/*.dat";
my $arc_dir = "/share/archive_dir/";

for my $file (glob $old_loc) {
    move ($file, $arc_dir) or die $!;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You might have better luck with the [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) function (although you must be careful with it).

```
print system("mv -v /share/cust/abc/*.dat /share/archive_dir/");
```

Comment: Of course, should the filename have spaces, braces, parenthesis, quotes, or other interpreted-by-the-shell characters, you just made jdamae's life a living hell :-( Better to use a glob solution, IMNSHO.

Comment: IMO you should never use a system call if there is a pure perl way.