# Copy file that have specified name in the file name

Tags: perl

I know simple copy like below,it able to copy file from one directory to another.

Code:

```
use File::Copy;

copy ("C:\Test\abc.txt","C:\Test2\abc.txt") or die "Copy failed: $!";
```

What I trying to do here is i got one file that user consistent update it and they will add the latest date behind the file name EG. `abc_20141111.txt`. Can I just ignore the date and copy the files?

Expected result: Copy the file that have name `abc` inside the file name to another location. I wanted to ignore the date behind the underscore. What can I change to get expected result?

Eg. 
File name - abc_20141111.txt

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882378/perl-moving-files-using-wildcard

Comment: @bytepusher hmm, thats help. Anyway, newbie will not search wild card =/

Comment: funnily enough, google on File::Copy + wildcard turned up a stack overflow post with the answer. Glad this short post was good enough for you to figure it out. Did not feel like copy/pasting it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Perl's glob operator to get the list of files you need to open:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

my $old_dir = glob "C:/Modules/sharepoint/abc_*.xlsx";
my $new_dir = "C:/Modules/sharepoint/testing/";

copy ($old_dir,$new_dir);
```

Comment: When you want to tell thanks to someone you can add a comment and when you want to put your code in the question itself you can modify. Dont try to add answers as it will cause redundancy.

Comment: Thanks to bytepusher for commenting "possible duplicate". And find the solution there.

Comment: Are you trying to put all the files of extension .xlsx into the destination folder ?

Comment: @Praveen Nop, I trying to pull the only file that consist of `abc` in the file name. In my folder , there are mutilple .xlsx files with different name. `abc` is unique, so above code work for me.

Comment: @Praveen thats why I am sure that the name `abc` is unique, and only file. So it will grab the only file.hmm?

Comment: If there is one file then your code works for sure. If there are multiple files then you can put an array as @old_dir and then print all the files that have a similar match regex. Just for your concern. Thanks !!

Comment: @Praveen Thanks for teaching! I will mark this up for sure. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
use File::Copy;
my $file = 'abc_20141114.txt';
my $actualpath = 'D:\test';
my $destinpath = 'D:\newtest';
my $newfile = $file;
$newfile=~s/^([^\_]*)\_([^\.]*)\.txt$/$1.txt/i;
copy("$actualpath\\$file", "$destinpath\\$newfile") && print "Success\n";
```